# Cycle Function stops working after sometime

Tags: jquery-cycle

I have two cycle functions to be used on my page. It works for few minutes and then stops working.

Script 1 :

```
                   <script type='text/javascript'>          
                   function pageLoad(sender, args){$('#Vertical').cycle({ 
                   fx: '" + Effect + "'
                   ,sync: 0,
                   prev:'#Verticalprev',
                   next:'#Verticalnext'
                    if (Easing != "0")
                       ,easing: '" + Easing + "'

                   });
                    //On mouseover pause the slider
                   $('#Vertical').mouseover(function() {
                   $('#Vertical').cycle('pause');
                   return false;
                   });

                    //On mouseout start the slider
                   $('#Vertical').mouseout(function() { 
                   $('#Vertical').cycle('resume');
                   }); 

                   }</script>
```

Script 2 :

```
                   <script type='text/javascript'>                       
                   function pageLoad(sender, args){$('#Horizontal').cycle({ 
                   fx: '" + Effect + "'
                   ,sync: 0,
                   prev:'#prev',
                   next:'#next'
                    if (Easing != "0")
                       ,easing: '" + Easing + "'

                   });


                    //On mouseover pause the slider
                   $('#Horizontal').mouseover(function() {
                   $('#Horizontal').cycle('pause');
                   return false;
                   });

                    //On mouseout start the slider
                   $('#Horizontal').mouseout(function() { 
                   $('#Horizontal').cycle('resume');
                   }); 

                   }</script>
```

Can any one help me with this?